# What special significance does the eigendecomposition of a mixed density operator hold over other pure state decompositions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, density

It is known that in general, a mixed state can have multiple pure state decompositions. However, it has a unique eigendecomposition in the absence of degenerate eigenvalues. What is the special significance of this eigendecomposition over other pure state decompositions for the same density matrix?

Comment: P.S: I do understand that the eigenstates are orthogonal whereas in any other decomposition the constituent states need not be orthogonal. Is there something more?

Comment: No, there is nothing more mathematically. But, those eigenstates are pretty important physically as the unique orthogonal states of the mixed system.  Give them a little more respect!

Comment: The spectral decomposition is special because it identifies the operator (in this case the density matrix) in a one-to-one fashion.

Comment: Sorry I should have made my question more precise. Lets denote the eigendecomposition as ${\rho=\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}|\psi_{i}\rangle\langle \psi_{i}|}$ and some other general decomposition as ${\rho=\sum_{k} p_{k} \rho_{k}}$ . Is the distribution of eigenvalues ${\lambda_{i}}$ optimal in any sense compared to the distribution of ${p_{k}}$'s? Are there any relations/inequalities that hold generically?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it has a special significance in terms of compressibility of information. For a state ${\rho}$ with an eigendecomposition,

${\rho=\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}|\psi_{i}\rangle\langle \psi_{i}|}$

the Von Neumann entropy ${S(\rho)}$is defined as,

${S(\rho)=-\mathrm{tr} \rho \log \rho=\sum_{i} \lambda_{i} \log \lambda_{i}}$

For any general pure state decomposition $\rho=\sum_{k} p_{k}\rho_{k}$, the Shannon entropy ${H(\{p_{k}\})}$ for the particular ensemble is defined as,

${H(\{p_{k}\})=-\sum_{k} p_{k} \log p_{k}}$

and the following inequality always holds true,

${H(\{p_{k}\}) \geq S(\rho)}$

with the equality being satisfied only when ${\{p_{k}\}}$ decomposition is the eigendecomposition itself.

Thus, the Shannon entropy of any pure state decomposition of a mixed state can never be less than the Von Neumann entropy of the state. This is due to the fact that in the eigendecomposition, the constituent states, being orthogonal, are perfectly distinguishable and hence correspond to minimal Shannon entropy.